# React Instance Config. Why are onReject: methods not calling the correct actions?

Tags: reactjs

I have instance config setup in React to call instances of actions, which in turn call instances of other action when resolved or rejected.

For Example,

I start by calling the below action which checks the password policy. So if the correct format of password is entered, it fires the onResolve: nethod which calls a second validation action, or fires the onReject: method which calls an action to display an error (incorrect password policy in this case).

```
 // Check password policy action.
    instanceName: "Forgot password account activation passwords match password policy",
    instanceId: "YaBnXPPdya",
    onResolve: "validateFormValuesAreEqual:BbFDnBZR5j",  // Run password match action (see below)
    onReject: "addErrorMessage:vjBahvsD3c"  // Policy error display action
```

Here is the second action, which checks if the password / confirm password match and either calls a method to update the backend (doActiveAccountRequest) or, again performs an action to display an error, in the case 'Passwords do not match".

```
 // Check pasword / confirm password matched action
    instanceName: "Forgot password check assigned field values are the same for the account activation form",
    instanceId: "BbFDnBZR5j",
    onResolve: "doActivateAccountRequest:b5B9UcVQZX",
    onReject: "addErrorMessage:DxzK6Glkzo"  // Password Match error display action
```

For completeness, here's the instance config for the error messages.

```
{
        catalogueId: catalogue.id,
        instanceId: "vjBahvsD3c",
        props: {
            doThrow: true,
            "i18n:errorMessage": {
                en: "Incorrect Password Policy",
            }
        }
    },
    {
        catalogueId: catalogue.id,
        instanceId: "DxzK6Glkzo",
        props: {
            doThrow: true,
            "i18n:errorMessage": {
                en: "Passwords must match",
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue I have is this:

If the first action executes without error (password policy check), the next action in the sequence is called (password match check), which errors.. Say for example I typed in a password with the correct policy, but the confirm password didn't match it.

... But the error action executed is from the FIRST action (password policy check), not the action that errored (the SECOND password match check action).

In other words.. If the policy check succeeds and the password match doesnt... The error displayed is 'Incorrect Password Policy" instead of "Passwords must match" !

Some further investigation:

If I remove the onReject: method for the first action (which calls addErrorMessage:vjBahvsD3c), the onReject action addErrorMessage:DxzK6Glkzo is called, and, as expected displays "Passwords must match"

Why is the orReject: method of the first action being triggered when there is no error? is it because the second action is chained from it and that did throw an error?